# How to use supervisorctl on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, services

I'm trying to install [plumi](https://github.com/plumi/plumi.app/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.txt)

And I did `sudo apt-get install supervisor` but `./bin/supervisord` doesn't work, nor `./bin/supervisorctl status`

`sudo service supervisor status` shows that it's running but does not show what services are running so please tell me how supervisor work and how I could check what service are running

Comment: Were you able to execute `./bin/python bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -v` without errors?

Comment: Why you install supervisor? and how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Since Oct 2013 that repository hasn't been updated. The `bootstrap.py` script fails for me. I don't think you will have luck.

Comment: @braiam the one in the repo won't work you have to use http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py

Comment: @jobin yes read my reply

Comment: @Braiam I'll add more details tomorrow or wed as I dont have access to my computer now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have **Supervisor** installed? If no do this first:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Once this has completed, the supervisor daemon should already be started, as the prebuilt packages come with an init script that will also ensure the Supervisor is restarted after a system reboot. You can ensure this is the case by running:

```
sudo service supervisor restart
```

Now you can read the [link](http://booki.flossmanuals.net/plumi/_draft/_v/4.2/installation/) here for more information about installing Plumi.

**Edit:**
More information can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps).

Comment: of course it is installed and I tried to follow this guide before, didn't work, forgot what went wrong but... my issue now is with superisor and how to work with it and how to add plumi to it and so on

Comment: Editted the answer, with a link with information about how to use.

Comment: Note, you may need to `reread` and `update` if you change a supervisor service config (`.conf`) file: `sudo supervisorctl reread` and `sudo supervisorctl update`